# Does the web browser send down info to websites about the Windows 10 theme that an anonymous client is using?

Tags: javascript, css, windows-10, themes

I would like to display the css dark theme, if an anonymous user uses an os dark theme or the web browser theme is matching that color template.

I'm wondering if a feature like that exists, probably not. Just, it would be nice to have web browser giving that info to websites.

So, we can display the light or dark theme based on the user os theme palette.

Comment: does [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-detect-a-users-preferred-color-scheme-in-javascript-ec8ee514f1ef) answer your question?

Comment: No but you can use CSS and the properties that access the computers settings. This link might be of some help https://www.sitepoint.com/css-system-styles/

Comment: thanks for those links, they are really useful

Comment: i will go with the react approch of depperm medium article link, thanks